# "What letter?" in a title and in a question

Tags: phrases

If I title a worksheet "What Letter?", am I reducing the grammar too much? It's a worksheet for 5 year old ESL learners. So, obviously, I don't want to confuse them with a full sentence. But I also don't want to shorten the grammar to the point of causing a grammatical error. Also, since the worksheet has a big alligator and a dotted-line "A", I will naturally do a lot of pointing and asking "what letter?".

Comment: I have no idea what **What Letter?** might be supposed to mean as a title for a worksheet. And I'm a native speaker who's much more than 5 years old! Forget "grammar", and just ask yourself whether your words will ***mean*** anything to a child who doesn't even speak English.

Answer (score 1):

You could title your worksheet "QWERTYUIOP" and it will have absolutely no effect on the five year olds who won't read it, won't understand it even if they do read it and probably won't even realise that the squiggles represent language which has meaning.

Why would a full sentence confuse them any more?  The only people who will even look at the title are the adults (parents, teachers, teaching assistants etc) who will be doing the worksheet with the children. You can put a title for them "Identify the sound made by the letter" or whatever your worksheet is meant to teach.

For the children just colours and pictures.  (actually I think 5 is too young to start learning writing in English but that is an argument for another day)